# How to fix the double spacing in HTML after bullets?

Tags: html, magento, magento2, magento-1.7

I'm setting up a product listing for a Magento site and having trouble with removing the double spacing after bullets. How can I fix this simple problem?

At first, the main problem was that the bullets were not indenting correctly. However, I inputted a padding, but that only caused double spacing between the last bullet and my final sentence. I want the last sentence to align back to the "Always follow these..." sentence.

```
[<div><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Always follow these precautionary tips before, during, and after you use the test strips:</span></div>
<div style="padding: 15px 50px;">
<ul>
<li>Always consult with a Doctor or Healthcare Professional determines how often you should test and what your target ranges are for blood glucose results.</li>
<li>Remove only one test strip at a time from test strip vial. Recap vial immediately.</li>
<li>NEVER reuse test strips.</li>
<li>Dispose test strips immediately after use.</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div><strong>Case of 100 (2 Boxes of 50)</strong></div>][1]
```

[image: Image of Double Spacing on Site]

Comment: try `padding: 15px 50px 0px;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul{   
   margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Always follow these precautionary tips before, during, and after you use the test strips:</span></div>
<div style="padding: 15px 50px;">
<ul>
<li>Always consult with a Doctor or Healthcare Professional determines how often you should test and what your target ranges are for blood glucose results.</li>
<li>Remove only one test strip at a time from test strip vial. Recap vial immediately.</li>
<li>NEVER reuse test strips.</li>
<li>Dispose test strips immediately after use.</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div><strong>Case of 100 (2 Boxes of 50)</strong></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually want the last sentence "Case of 100..." to align with the "Always follow these precautionary..." sentence--the one right before the bullets.